# Unable to load DLL 'Magick.NET-Q16-x86.Native.dll': The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, magick.net

When I run project in visual studio, `Magick.NET v7.14.0.2` works fine but on deploying on windows server, it gives error:

> Unable to load DLL 'Magick.NET-Q16-x86.Native.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

**Complete exception:**

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'NativeMagickSettings' threw an exception. ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'Magick.NET-Q16-x86.Native.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E) at ImageMagick.Environment.NativeMethods.X86.Environment_Initialize() at ImageMagick.Environment.Initialize() at ImageMagick.MagickSettings.NativeMagickSettings..cctor() --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at ImageMagick.MagickSettings.NativeMagickSettings..ctor() at ImageMagick.MagickSettings..ctor() at ImageMagick.MagickImage..ctor() at projectname.controllername
```

Comment: Did you deploy that DLL along with your app?

Comment: yes I have confirmed, dll exists on deployed folder

Comment: Is it in the same folder as your executable?

Comment: yes, it is in projectRoot/bin folder